# Make a RandomChoice inside a RecurrenceTable at each time of use, rather than once at time of definition

Tags: evaluation, random, difference-equations

I recently watched the Numberphile video ["Chaos Game"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbKtFN71Lfs) and I am trying to recreate the phenomenon discussed therein. The video depicts the following process:

- First, draw 3 points somewhere within the unit square to form the vertices *A*, *B*, and *C* of a triangle.
- Also draw one additional starting-point *P* somewhere in the unit square.
- Now iterate the following process many times:

  - Choose one of the 3 vertices *A*, *B*, or *C* at random.
  - Draw the point *Q* that is halfway between *P* and the chosen vertex.
  - Let *Q* be the new *P*.

To perform this process using *Mathematica*, I begin by defining a function to generate a random point on the unit square:

```
randomPoint[] := {RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}
```

Using this function I randomly choose 3 vertices for my triangle:

```
vertices = Table[randomPoint[], {3}];
```

Now I just need to generate a list of points to mark. The first point is chosen at random; then each successive point is the average of the previous point and a randomly chosen vertex. So I thought a RecurrenceTable might do the trick:

```
points = RecurrenceTable[
    {p[0] == randomPoint[], p[n+1] == Mean[{p[n], RandomChoice@vertices}]},
    p, {n, 10}];
```

I expected a result that looks like

```
ListPlot[{points, vertices},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full]
```

> [image]

but instead I got

> [image]

At my best guess, rather than make a *new* RandomChoice of vertex for each iteration of the recurrence, this seems to be making a *single* RandomChoice at definition-time, so I wind up always approaching halfway to the same vertex in every step. So how can I rewrite this to make an independent random choice of vertex in each step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not *have to* use `RecurrenceTable` you can use `NestList` to get the desired result:

```
pts = NestList[Mean[{#, RandomChoice[vertices]}] &, randomPoint[], 20];

ListPlot[{pts, vertices}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> None, Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
sq[n_, m_] := Module[{pts = RandomReal[1, {m + 1, 2}], p, ic, f},
  {p, ic} = {pts[[1 ;; m]], pts[[-1]]};
  f = FoldList[(#2 + #1)/2 &, ic, RandomChoice[p, n]];
  Graphics[{Green, PointSize[0.02], Point[p], Red, PointSize[0.01], 
    Point[f]}]
  ]
```

e.g.

```
Partition[Table[sq[10000, 3], 9], 3] // Grid
```

[image]